# Bootstrap 4 Columns float style like Bootstrap 3 is it possible?

Tags: css-float, multiple-columns, bootstrap-4, dynamic-columns

i start developing with bootstrap 4 and now i found this problem :
when using bootstrap 3 column system, because it uses float, we could insert multiple columns inside a row and it wold fill the space depending on the "col-size" specified, like this :

http://codepen.io/seltix/pen/QpXvRJ

```
 -------   -------   -------
| COL 1 | | COL 2 | | COL 3 |
|       |  -------   -------
|       | | COL 4 | | COL 5 |
 -------   -------   -------

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 panel height-1">
      <div class="bg-danger">this box is a slider with fixed col-6 width and fixes 2 blue boxes height</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 panel height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 panel height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 panel height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 panel height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 panel height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but with the bootstrap 4 flex system each element uses the full height of the row and the result is this :

http://codepen.io/seltix/pen/PprmVE

```
 -------   -------   -------
| COL 1 | | COL 2 | | COL 3 |
|       |  -------   -------
|       |
 -------   -------
| COL 4 | | COL 5 |
 -------   -------

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 card height-1">
      <div class="bg-danger">this box is a slider with fixed col-6 width and fixes 2 blue boxes height</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 card height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 card height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 card height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 card height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 card height-2">
      <div class="bg-info">blue boxes count may change depending on the content.<br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i already google it and search on bootstrap 4 documentation for this but i dont find any solution. the closest i cound was card-columns, a masonry-like example but i dont think it work for this example since i cant specify the columns/cards width.
thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can get 3.x grid "float" behavior in Bootstrap 4 using the utility classes.

Use `d-block` to change the row from display:flex to display:block. Then use `float-left` on each col..

http://www.codeply.com/go/BmN6ZYQdGm

```
 <div class="row d-block">
        <div class="col-md-6 float-left card height-1">
            <div class="bg-danger">1
                <br>this box is a slider with fixed col-6 width and fixes 2 blue boxes height</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left card height-2">
            <div class="bg-info">2
                <br>blue boxes count may change depending on the content.
                <br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left card height-2">
            <div class="bg-info">3
                <br>blue boxes count may change depending on the content.
                <br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left card height-2">
            <div class="bg-info">4
                <br>blue boxes count may change depending on the content.
                <br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left card height-2">
            <div class="bg-info">5
                <br>blue boxes count may change depending on the content.
                <br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left card height-2">
            <div class="bg-info">6
                <br>blue boxes count may change depending on the content.
                <br>if there are only 1 blue box the col size will change from 3 to 6 in the PHP</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/BmN6ZYQdGm

---

Related: [Bootstrap 4 - I don't want columns to have the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710785/bootstrap-4-i-dont-want-columns-to-have-the-same-height/44710904)

Comment: great! thanks :D i did try to pull-left the columns but dint work, the d-block did the trick!
one last related question, after this row, to continue with normal column what is the best option? a clearfix at the end of the row like this? http://www.codeply.com/go/nMG6vNDoZh