# Bootstrap - I don't want columns to have the same height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In this bootstrap 4 example the 2 columns have the same height.
I do not want this. 
Is there a quick fix for this ?

```
    <div class="col-lg-3 card bg-faded">
      <h1><small>Some favorites</small></h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Celery root</li>
        <li>Spaghetti Squash</li>
        <li>Killer Mushrooms</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <h1>Wild & Wicky Vegetables</h1>
      <p>Kale c.....t.</p>
    </div>
</div><!--row-->
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 is still flexbox based so columns in a row are equal height. Therefore d-block can still be used to "disable" flexbox and use `float-start` to float columns.

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

Yes, you can use `d-block` on the row, and `float-left` on the columns to make it work the Bootstrap 3.x way with floated columns instead of flexbox..

```
<div class="row d-block">
    <div class="col-lg-3 float-left">
        ..
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 float-left">
        ..
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/Ghhq1NbMDG

---

Related:
[Bootstrap 4 Columns float style like Bootstrap 3 is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43285745/bootstrap-4-columns-float-style-like-bootstrap-3-is-it-possible)
[Empty vertical space between columns in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173381/empty-vertical-space-between-columns-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, a simpler solution is to add 'h-100' class to the column you don't want to share the same height with. This makes the column 100% height of itself, not sharing the height of the other column in the row.