# Is there a way of get "real" floating with flexbox and bootstrap 4 with unequal high elements?

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to arange unequal high elements in a floating environment with bootstrap 4 and flexbox.

Without using flexbox in BS4 the elements are aranged in equal height ( `<div class="row">`). Applying flexbox like `<div class="row d-flex flex-wrap align-items-start">` I get the desired alignment but if the elements have an unequal height they - of course - don't float.

Is there a way to achieve this to look

[like the "former" BS3 bahaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAhBt.png) ?

I want to implement a general "algorithm" so that I can add elements without specifying the positions explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to get flexbox items to float.

However, you can override the `display:flexbox` on the Bootstrap 4 `row`, by using `d-block` and use the [float utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/float/). This has already be explained in several other questions.

[Bootstrap 4 - I don't want columns to have the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710785/bootstrap-4-i-dont-want-columns-to-have-the-same-height)
[Rearranging responsive Bootstrap 4 grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264243/rearranging-responsive-bootstrap-4-grid-layout/55264594#55264594)
[Bootstrap Responsive Columns Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169932/bootstrap-responsive-columns-height)
[Empty vertical space between columns in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173381/empty-vertical-space-between-columns-in-bootstrap-4/)

Note that `d-block` is a responsive class (`d-sm-block`, `d-md-block`, etc...) which allows you to override flexbox responsively on specific breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. It works exactly as it should